# django method return f'Edit {self.object.name}'

Tags: python

What does the return statement in the `get_headline` method do?
And also why am I getting a syntax error?

**Nota**: I am using python 2.7

Here is the class:

```
class Update(LoginRequiredMixin,SetHeadLinesMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CompanyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:dashboard')
    template_name = 'users/company_form.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.user.companies.all()

    def get_headline(self):
        return f'Edit {self.object.name}'
```

Comment: "note : i am using python 2.7" - well, there's your problem. f-string syntax is 3.6+.

Comment: sooo how can i overcome this problem :)

Comment: Get 3.6, or don't use f-strings.

Comment: ok ,  any idea on  how to accomplish the same thing , in python 2.7 !,